# convert hex to base 2 binary representation in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I believe that there is no snowflake function currently which can convert a hex to base 2 numbers
for example:
2303067e
to : 00100011000000110000011001111110
in a single udf function.
the values of hex will come from a table
so i would like to call function select hextobinary(column A)
and would like to get the output.

Input:2303067e
Output:00100011000000110000011001111110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What stops you from creating a UDF to do this?
For example this Python UDF can do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  hex2bin(arg1 string)
RETURNS int
LANGUAGE PYTHON 
VOLATILE
RUNTIME_VERSION=3.10
HANDLER='hex2bin'
AS $$
def hex2bin(x: str) -> int:
    return bin(int(x, 16))[2:]
$$;
```

Then:

```
select hex2bin('2303067e');
```

Output:

```
HEX2BIN('2303067E')
100011000000110000011001111110
```

Comment: @2023hpy You can mark the answer as correct then.

Comment: i am getting an error though now. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_udf_code.py", line 3, in hex2bin
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
 in function HEX2BIN with handler hex2bin

Comment: Can you post a sample of the hex you are trying to convert to binary?

Comment: i modified the script for null values and seem to work.